# Php Execution in subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, execution

I have some trouble with php execution in subfolder. I have htaccess file in main directory of the website and I am unable to change it. the codes there are  :

```
RemoveHandler .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phps .rhtml .phtml .cgi .py .pl .pm .rb .asp .asc .aspx .ascx .sh .htm
```

SetHandler default-handler

ForceType text/plain

Now I need to add htaccess and override this main htaccess. Could anyone help me what to add in htaccess ? Thanks.